# Array and syntax of counting indexes by 2

Tags: python, arrays

Given a simple list:

```
nums = [2,4,6,8,10]
print(nums[nums[0]])
```

Can someone explain how `print(nums[nums[0]])` results in the display of 6 which is considered index 2 of the list?

If I modify the code to `print(nums[nums[1]])`, the result is 10.

What exactly does this python syntax doing to the index values?

Comment: there is nothing to do with python `nums[1]` value is 4 so `nums[nums[1]]`  jsut become `nums[4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nums[0]` is `2`

`nums[nums[0]]` is `nums[2]` is `6`

---

`nums[1]` is `4`

`nums[nums[1]]` is `nums[4]` is `10`